# Printing row based on datestamp condition of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-lab, datestamp

**Background:**
I have a DataFrame ('`weather_tweets`') containing two columns of interest, `weather` (weather on the planet Mars) and `date` (the date the weather relates). Structure as follows:
[image]

**Objective:**
I am trying to write code that will determine the latest datestamp (`date` column) and print that row's corresponding `weather` column value.
**Sample rows:**
Here is a sample row:

```
weather_tweets = [
    ('tweet', 'weather', 'date'),
    ('Mars Weather@MarsWxReport·Jul 15InSight sol 58', 'InSight sol 580 (2020-07-14) low -88.8ºC (-127.8ºF) high -8.4ºC (16.8ºF) winds from the WNW at 5.9 m/s (13.3 mph) gusting to 15.4 m/s (34.4 mph) pressure at 7.80 hPa, '2020-07-14')]
```

**My code:**
Thus far, I have only been able to formulate some messy code that will return the latest dates in order, but it's pretty useless for my expected results:
`latest_weather = weather_tweets.groupby(['tweet', 'weather'])['date'].transform(max) == weather_tweets['date']`
`print(weather_tweets[latest_weather])`

Any advice on how to reach the desired result would be much appreciated.

Comment: So You want to print only 1 row with the latest date from entire dataframe?

Comment: Could you share some sample rows in text format?

Comment: @MabelVillalba - sure, I have added a sample row.

Comment: @ipj - Correct, however I only need to print the content of that row's 'weather' column value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
weather_tweets[weather_tweets.date == weather_tweets.date.max()].weather
```

You can add `to_frame()` at the end to obtain more elegant dataframe result:

```
weather_tweets[weather_tweets.date == weather_tweets.date.max()].weather.to_frame()
```

Or create new dataframe:

```
df_latest = weather_tweets.loc[weather_tweets.date == weather_tweets.date.max(),['weather','date']]
df_max.columns = ['latest_weather','latest_date']
```

Comment: Thanks @ipj. Is there anyway I could save each value in a variable, so I can print more elegantly? e.g save the latest date in a 'latest_date' variable and save the string in the 'weather' cell in a 'latest_weather' variable? Your code does print the weather, but also the index and data type